How to enable forward slash for directory names on autocompletion with hrsh7th / cmp-path plugin?
I use this plugin https://github.com/hrsh7th/cmp-path for autocompletion, including paths in the command mode.
And the problem is that on a tab press the name is completed, but the slash is not appended for directories.
For example, I have a src directory in my current direcotry (for other directories the behavior seems to be the same, so it's not related to this particular name).
When I type: :eSpacesrtab
The command line is populated with the path, src instead of src/.

I've found this question on github, which seems to be exactly the same I'm having (even the config example is the same), but it didn't work for me, for some reason.
I have this in my vimrc:
-- Use cmdline & path source for ':' (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
  sources = cmp.config.sources({
    {
      name = 'path',
      option = {
        trailing_slash = true
      }
    }
  }, {
    { name = 'cmdline' }
  })
})

Everything seems to be correct, but I have this as the output of the :CmpStatus:
# ready source names
- buffer
- vsnip

# unused source names
- cmdline
- path

# unknown source names
- nvim_lsp


Could someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Use the plugin’s issue tracker.

Please don't post images of text; in particular, the last image of :CmpStatus would be more useful as a block of text.

Figured it out finally. Posting it just in case someone has something similar.
TLDR;
Set option = {  treat_trailing_slash = false } for the hrsh7th/cmp-cmdline plugin in addition to the option = {  trailing_slash = true } for the hrsh7th/cmp-path one (this should be in your vimrc):
-- Use cmdline & path source for ':' (if you enabled `native_menu`, this won't work anymore).
cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
  mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
  sources = cmp.config.sources({
    { name = 'path', option = {  trailing_slash = true } }
  }, {
    { name = 'cmdline', option = {  treat_trailing_slash = false } }
  })
})


The hrsh7th/cmp-cmdline plugin, which I found to use also, has this in its docs (https://github.com/hrsh7th/cmp-cmdline):

treat_trailing_slash: boolean
Default: true
vim.fn.getcompletion can return path items. unfortunately, that items
has trailing slash so we don't narrowing with next directory with
pressing /.
if you turnd on this option, cmp-cmdline removes trailing slash
automatically.

